# Rails AJAX call to clear form input data

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

After a successful creation of a record via AJAX, the rails form remains in place, with the data that was used to create the new record.

form call

```
<%= form_with model: Usercontent.new, data: {'js-usercontent-form' => true} do |form| %>

<form data-js-usercontent-form="true" action="/usercontents?locale=en" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post">
```

Attempting to reset the form with no data via `reset`

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  $('[data-js-usercontent-form]').on("ajax:success", function(event, data, status, xhr){
    var usercontent = $(xhr.responseText).hide();
    $('#usercontents').append(usercontent);
    usercontent.fadeIn(1000);
    document.getElementById('data-js-usercontent-form').reset();
  });

  $('[data-js-usercontent-id]').on("ajax:success", function(event, data, status, xhr){
    var usercontent_id = xhr.responseJSON.id;
    $('[data-js-usercontent-id=' + usercontent_id + ']').hide();
  });
});
```

unfortunately fails.  There are multiple fields and thus the question is whether there is a way to clear all the fields to their default (empty or prompt) state **update** while maintaining the integrity of the destroy block?

Comment: That should work, at least if the ID is correct. Did you confirm you are targeting the correct element?

Comment: I believe so.  Question updated with form call

Comment: And the rendered HTML?

Comment: added the relevant snippet; however the code works up to `usercontent.fadeIn(1000);`  so the rendering is not the issue.  The last statement does not get properly handled.

Comment: May be your ajax call didn't success at all

Comment: @jerome, exactly as I thought, the ID is not present, check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it seems you are targetting the form with `ID="data-js-usercontent-form"`, but in the rendered HTML, I don't see that ID. Youi are indicating that usercontent is working, but it is targeting a different element.

Please change the call to create the form:

```
<%= form_with model: Usercontent.new, id: 'data-js-usercontent-form', data: {'js-usercontent-form' => true} do |form| %>
```

This error should have been logged in your developer tools console, I'd always advise to check it in case you run into JS issues.

Comment: Console previously giving: `TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null`. answer html rendering:  `<form data-js-usercontent-form="true" data-id="data-js-usercontent-form" action="/usercontents"[...]>` a bit off.  Proper syntax is to remove id from the data hash: `<%= form_with model: Usercontent.new, id: 'data-js-usercontent-form', data: {'js-usercontent-form' => true} do |form| %>`. upvoting for proper directions. will await answer update for checkmark..